# How to migrate from mdadm (RAID 1) from 2 HDD's to 2 SDD's

Tags: 20.04, ssd, raid, mdadm

I would like to migrate a Dell PowerEdge R210 II from two HDD's (running RAID 1 via mdadm) to two SSD's of slightly larger size (512GB vs 500GB).   The system currently boots using BIOS (not UEFI)

What is the simplest way to do this?   I already tried failing and removing one of the HDD's and replacing it with one of the SDD's and adding the SSD to mdadm.  That worked fine and it synced fairly quickly.  But things went south on the next step.   I then shutdown, removed the old HDD, rebooted but the system didn't find Grub and/or MBR on the SSD and wasn't able to boot.  It seems like I'm missing a critical step?

I put one of the HDD's back into the system (so now it has one HDD and one SDD).  the machine will once again boot.   How do I get the machine to boot with JUST the SDD so I can then add the other SDD via mdadm and get back to RAID 1 (or perhaps just get rid of RAID 1 and use a single SSD)

Here is output of sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0.

Interestingly, it seems like the machine is booting off of sda1 (one of the old HDD's) but using only sdb1 (one of the SDD's), so degraded RAID 1.  I say that because a) the machine will boot, which it won't if I just have the SDD plugged in). And b) performance is blazing fast, suggesting it is reading/writing to the SDD.  at this point I have a working, albeit incorrectly configured machine so don't want to do anything to mess it up.

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0   9.1M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/94
loop1     7:1    0   9.1M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
loop2     7:2    0  99.2M  1 loop  /snap/core/10859
loop3     7:3    0  99.2M  1 loop  /snap/core/10908
loop4     7:4    0  55.5M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1988
loop5     7:5    0  55.4M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1944
sda       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0 419.1G  0 part  
├─sda2    8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5    8:5    0  46.7G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb       8:16   0   477G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0 419.1G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0   419G  0 raid1 /
├─sdb2    8:18   0     1K  0 part  
└─sdb5    8:21   0  46.7G  0 part  
steve@rc-dev3:~$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
[sudo] password for steve: 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Nov  5 14:31:28 2013
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 439320384 (418.97 GiB 449.86 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 439320384 (418.97 GiB 449.86 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Mar 28 12:36:06 2021
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rc-dev3:0  (local to host rc-dev3)
              UUID : bb446c76:98f5d085:3cfcaf6a:0a0f30d6
            Events : 67609

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       2       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

[image: HDD (bootable)]

[image: SSD Active, won't boot]

Comment: Is there a reason not to go the generic route: create personal backup, remove hdd, insert sdds, install and restore backup?  Or the alternative remove hdds, insert sdds, install, mount hdds, extract personal data from hdds?

Comment: I tried clonezilla and ReaR and had issues with both, possibly because they couldn’t handle the raid setup or the slightly different sizes of HDD and SDD.

Comment: p.s.I have several dev ops tools installed and confused and am trying to avoid having to reinstall and configure them , which is why I’m not doing a fresh install, though it may come to that 

Comment: That is a reason ;-) plus it is probably a very good learning experience. But ... from what I see here I would assume it should work. 1st idea: reinstall uefi and/or bootrepair the boot?  Maybe that did not get copied over from the hdds? or maybe it points to the wrong disk labe.

Comment: thank you @Rinzwind  the HDD's are setup with BIOS so I don't think UEFI is an option.   I did try boot-repair (changing the server to UEFI and booting from a Ubuntu Live USB stick).    Boot-repair made some changes but then said it encountered an error and stated it couldn't find a UEFI device(s).  (suggesting boot-repair can't help older BIOS-based servers).  The report stated, "Unknown BootLoader on sdb"

when I attempted boot-repair it was with only the SSD attached.  I could try again with both the HDD and SDD attached (?).  Perhaps it would find the boot loader on sba and copy to sba?

Comment: It is worth investigating the boot repair error. I believe that seems to be the path to fixing it. You need a live session boot without uefi. The live session error probably is that: it wants to eufi repair a mbr boot. not gonna happen. If you want uefi you need probably to install it on the disk and then boot from it.